# iPhone Bug with Html Tables and Anchors

Tags: html, iphone, html-table, anchor

I have a table with a list of items in it.  Shown below.

The problem is when this table is displayed on the iPhone 5/4, it still shows up, but the thread "Last Post" is a much larger font.  Its increased by maybe .3em.  The second issue is when I click on the first link in the first column inside the iPhone, it doesn't actually work.  None of the anchor tags work.  Which is really weird and I just don't understand what is going on.  Please help?

**UPDATE**
Here is a link to the CSS Doc.  Just compare it to the calendarTable attributes.
https://league.rdnation.com/content/main.css

```
<table class="calendarTable" id="messages">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Title
                    </th>
                    <th>Last Received
                    </th>
                    <th>Last Post
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    <tr class="forumTopicRow calCurrentDateEvent">
                        <td>
                            <a class="b" href="/messages/view/16">Message Title</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            5 minutes ago
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            asdfasdfasd by <b>Veggie Delight</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>           
                    <tr class="forumTopicRow ">
                        <td>
                            <a href="/messages/view/14">Test1</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            10 months ago
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Check it twice by <b>Veggie Delight</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>           
                    <tr class="forumTopicRow ">
                        <td>
                            <a href="/messages/view/13">Message</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            10 months ago
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            This is a Message to by <b>Veggie Delight</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>           
                    <tr class="forumTopicRow ">
                        <td>
                            <a href="/messages/view/12">Message</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            10 months ago
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Do you like this by <b>Veggie Delight</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>           
                    <tr class="forumTopicRow ">
                        <td>
                            <a href="/messages/view/9">Testing</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            one year ago
                        </td>
                        <td>
                             This is a new messa by <b></b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>           
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Can you post your CSS?

Comment: @JacquesGoulet CSS is located here: https://league.rdnation.com/content/main.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey mate I didnt see your code but recently I fixed my newsletter by adding

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
```

in your td style

I had the same problem.

Try it might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, going through your css, the only thing I saw that may cause an issue for you is,  (After doing find table in the document.) The 6th (found word) of table that popped up, with table headers as well, has a font-size of 100%.  That's a pretty risky move and chances are one of your table headers is taking on a different size within the iphone, (even if you can't see it.) causing your font size to increase.  To see if that's correct simply change the text size to something other than a percentage to test.

As far as link goes, i'm pretty sure you're sending them to the wrong place...
remove the / at the beginning of your links and you should be fine.